# I try to make a Tampermonkey Userscript that Automatically Click on a picture when show up

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, browser, tampermonkey

There's a Halloween related game on a website. In the game to earn points you must click on pictures which appear randomly. I was wondering if anyone could help me create JavaScript for Tampermonkey on Chrome that will automatically click on these pictures when they show up.

Thanks!

Here is the code for one of the pictures:

```
<img style="cursor:pointer;" src="https://static.ncore.cc/static/images/spooky2k18/9.png">
```

Comment: I want to create something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbkEFkSPD2Y

Answer (score 0):

```
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

jQuery('[src^="https://static.ncor"]').load(function(){
     alert("hi do something")
})
```

perhaps something like this? Do you have an example of which page this happens on? I can give you a better answer that way.

Comment: It's a torrent site. Images can pop up on every page, for example: index.php, torrents.php etc.